# max and min rates for the particular area -lambda query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

```
my table looks like-
  Area    MaxRate  MinRate Quarter year
    crossing  1000     800     1       2013
    crossing  900      700     2       2013
    crossing  800      600     3       2013

    crossing  700      500     4       2013
    crossing  600      500     1       2012
    crossing  550      450     2       2012
    crossing  500      400     3       2012

    crossing  450      350     4       2012
    indroper  2000     1500    1       2013
    indroper  1800     1500    2       2013
```

```
 I want max and min rates for the particular area in current year as -

 **Area    MaxRate  MinRate       year**
 crossing  1000     500           2013
```

please help me to find the query in LINQ-lambda notation

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy` to do this:

```
var results = table.GroupBy(row => new { Area = row.Area, Year = row.year })
                   .Select(g => new { 
                                       Area = g.Key.Area, 
                                       MaxRate = g.Max(i => i.MaxRate),
                                       MinRate = g.Min(i => i.MinRate),
                                       Year = g.Key.Year
                                    });
```

Comment: @Pradeep What is it doing differently than you want?

Comment: It is returning records for each year. But with the help of your solution I tried only groupBy area & problem is solved.Thanx for help.

Comment: @Pradeep What I provided will do by area by year - if you just want by area, just group by area.  You can also do `.Where(row => row.Year == 2013)` before the group by if you just want "this year".